# AWS Athena - Partition Projection not returning any results

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

**S3 folder structure**

s3://bucket/subfolder/data/20211201/

s3://bucket/subfolder/data/20211202/

**select * from test where dt = '20211201'**

**When I query the table, I don't get any results.**

Athena Table with Partition Projection

```
create external table `test`(
    id int
    ,name string
)
partitioned by (
    dt string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'parquet.column.index.access'='true') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://bucket/subfolder/data/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='parquet',
  'has_encrypted_data'='false', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1637182794',
  "projection.enabled"= "true",
  "projection.dt.type" = "date",
  "projection.dt.range" = "20211201,NOW",
  "projection.dt.format" = "yyyyMMdd",
  "projection.dt.interval" = "1",
  "projection.dt.interval.unit" = "DAYS",
  "storage.location.template" = "s3://bucket/subfolder/data/${dt}/"
  )
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the partition projection configuration. Are you sure it's not just a typo in for example the storage location template? Does `aws s3 ls s3://bucket/subfolder/data/20211201/` list files? What if you run `SELECT * FROM test` do you get anything at all?